# Using lmodern as default teletype font

Tags: fonts, latin-modern

I would like to use `lmodern` as my default teletype font, while using other fonts for sans etc.

So far I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{cantarell}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{???}

\begin{document}
{\ttfamily Hello in lmodern }
\end{document}
```

What do I have to replace the `???` with in order for the lmodern to be used as the default teletype?

Comment: Nothing, just remove `\renewcommand*\ttdefault{???}`

Comment: Loading `lmodern` after `cantarell` will override the choice of the sans serif font; change the loading order, if you want Cantarell as sans serif font. As David says, nothing is necessary for the monospaced font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `cantarell` package with the `defaultsans` option sets the sans serif font to Cantarell by redefining `\sfdefault`. However, `lmodern` does

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
```

so loading it after `cantarell` will override the specification made by this package. The `lmodern` package sets `\ttdefault` to `lmtt` (Latin Modern Typewriter), so you get served by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{cantarell}

\begin{document}
{\sffamily Hello in Cantarell}

{\ttfamily Hello in lmodern}
\end{document}
```

without doing anything for `\ttdefault`.

[image]